# content does not change using HotModuleReplacementPlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, webpack-4, hot-module-replacement

First problem :

Trying `HMR` example given in webpack documentation in this link : https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/.  As mentioned in title : "[Gotchas](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#gotchas)", i tried removing child which was added when `app` loads for the first time, then i tried calling `component()` function again to append in new element returned triggered by changed `print.js` module.

In browser i get this when i change text in `print.js`, which seems to work but when i press the button i keep getting old text value in `print.js`

Browser console screen shot on change in `print.js` : 
[image]

Screen shot when i click <kbd>click me and check the console</kbd> button (its not the text i have updated, its old text) : 
[image]

My entry file `main.js` :

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import printMe from './print.js';

function component() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');

  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');

  btn.innerHTML = 'Click me and check the console!';
  btn.onclick = printMe;

  element.appendChild(btn);

  return element;
}

let element = component(); // Store the element to re-render on print.js changes
document.body.appendChild(element);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./print.js', function() {
    console.log('Accepting the updated printMe module!');
    document.body.removeChild(element);
    element = component(); // Re-render the "component" to update the click handler
    document.body.appendChild(element);
  });
}
```

My `Print.js` file :

```
export default function printMe() {
  console.log('Updating123 and print.js...');
}
```

Second Problem :

I simplified previous problem to return simple text from `print.js` and console logged text inside module.hot and found even weird behaviors:

`component()` function triggered from `module.hot.accept` callback function logs same old text on first time change inside `print.js`(​simple text4​​ is text before changes done in `print.js`)

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?81da:223 [WDS] App hot update...
log.js:24 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
main.jsx:14 Accepting the updated printMe module!
main.jsx:15 <div>​simple text4​</div>​
log.js:24 [HMR] Updated modules:
log.js:24 [HMR]  - ./src/print.js
log.js:24 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

& changing second time inside `print.js` does not log anything in browser console :

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?81da:223 [WDS] App hot update...
log.js:24 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
log.js:24 [HMR] Updated modules:
log.js:24 [HMR]  - ./src/print.js
log.js:24 [HMR] App is up to date.
```

`main.js` code :

```
import printMe from './print.js';

function component() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = printMe();

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./print.js', function() {
    console.log('Accepting the updated printMe module!');
    console.log(component());
  });
}
```

`print.js` code :

```
export default function printMe() {
  var a = 'simple text2';
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling module transformation in .babelrc finally worked. This line did the trick :  **"modules": false**

My current .babelrc file looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": 52
        },
        "modules": false,
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```